# Can you return a list of Teams channels a user is a part of?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to write a script that would copy a user's teams and channels from Microsoft Teams. I was able to copy the Team without any issue, but I can't figure out a way to copy the specific channels.

The only thing I was able to find was the Get-TeamChannel cmdlet, but this only lists all the channels a team has.

[Get-TeamChannel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/get-teamchannel?view=teams-ps)

Comment: If its Microsoft Graph then you can try this:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{teams-d}/channels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to call the [List channel Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request) by passing the Team Id Make sure have appropriate permissions

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{TeamId}/channels
```

It returns the number of channels for the Team, Members are added at Team scope not at channel scope once a user become part of team as owner or member they can access the channels within that Team
The best approach can be to list down the [Teams for a user](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedTeams) is part of and passing the team id to channel API.